# Current through resistor in opamp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have problems calculating the current through the resistors `Re`, `Rr`

Maybe someone can help me with this, I don't know how to handle the wire from `+` to `-`.

Here is Falstad code:

[Circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2011.086722712598126%2050%205%2050%0A172%20-32%20160%20-80%20160%200%207%202.95%205%200%200%200.5%20%252B%20Voltage%0Aa%20128%20176%20240%20176%208%2015%20-15%201000000%202.9499705005899886%202.9500000000000006%20100000%0Ar%200%20160%2080%20160%200%2010000%0Ar%20144%2048%20240%2048%200%2010000%0Ar%20384%20192%20384%20272%200%2010000%0Ag%20384%20288%20384%20320%200%0Aw%20-32%20160%200%20160%200%0Aw%2080%20160%20128%20160%200%0Aw%20128%20160%20128%2048%200%0Aw%20144%2048%20128%2048%200%0Aw%20240%2048%20240%20176%200%0Aw%20240%20176%20384%20176%200%0Aw%20384%20176%20384%20192%200%0Aw%20384%20272%20384%20288%200%0Aw%20128%20192%20-32%20192%200%0Aw%20384%20176%20528%20176%200%0Ap%20528%20176%20528%20272%201%200%0Aw%20-32%20192%20-32%20160%200%0Ag%20528%20288%20528%20320%200%0Aw%20528%20288%20528%20272%200%0Ao%202%2064%200%204099%200.000152587890625%200.00009765625%200%202%202%203%0A)

Here is the circuit:

[image]

Comment: Hint: What voltage will the output drive the inverting input to?

Comment: to the same as the non-inverting input?!

Comment: For a perfect amplifier, yes. If that is true, then the voltage at each end of the input resistor is the same. Now calculate the current :)

Comment: Ok so the current will be Zero for an ideal opamp?

Comment: Glad you have it figured out. A real amplifier will have a bit of offset but not usually very much.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will go ahead :) have a nice day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101186/discussion-between-peter-smith-and-adaptive).